# UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'Profile' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i am writing a django views as shown:-

```
def feed(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user=request.user
    profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=user)
    userfollowing=FollowingProfiles.objects.filter(Profile=profile)
    for following in userfollowing:
        username=following.ProfileName
        useraccount=User.objects.filter(username=username)
        Profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=useraccount)
        Post=post.objects.filter(Profile=Profile)
        comment=comment.objects.filter(post=Post)
        final_post_queryset=final_post_queryset+Post
        final_comment_queryset=final_comment_queryset+comment
    return render(request,'feed/feed.html',{'final_comment_queryset':final_comment_queryset,'final_post_queryset':final_post_queryset})
else:
    redirect('signup')
```

while template feed.html is:-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

{% for p in final_post_queryset %}
   {{ p.DatePosted }}
   <img src="{{ p.Picture.url }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

while the error is:-
[image]

so the error is in the 3rd line of view

```
profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you already imported the `Profile` module (with `from .models import Profile` or the like), and are confused as to why it doesn't exist (if you haven't, you need to add that import to the top of your file).

Even if you have imported it, this code won't work. Your problem is you assigned to the name `Profile` at function scope, making it a local variable, and local variables are local (but initially empty) from the *beginning* of the function. Trying to access them before they're assigned to raises the `UnboundLocalError` you're seeing (that error is *only* raised when you try to read from a local name before you've assigned to it; it can't be raised simply by failing to import a module, which would simply raise a `NameError`). You couldn't see the globally imported `Profile` even if you *did* import it, because within the function, `Profile` must be local or global, it can't be both.

To fix, choose a different name for your local variable so the global `Profile` remains accessible:

```
def feed(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user=request.user
        profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=user)  # This line is fine!
        userfollowing=FollowingProfiles.objects.filter(Profile=profile)
        for following in userfollowing:
            username=following.ProfileName
            useraccount=User.objects.filter(username=username)
            # Use lowercase profile, not Profile
            # Profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=useraccount)  # This line was the problem!
            profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=useraccount)  # This line is the solution!
            Post = post.objects.filter(Profile=profile)  # Change to match new name
            ... rest of your code ...
```

You were already using lowercase `profile` correctly earlier, and never seem to need it again, so I just reused the name.

Comment: I also use lowercase letter in it

Comment: @Gagan: You're looking at the wrong line. A *later* line in your code does `Profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=useraccount)`, and *that's* the line that makes `Profile` a local variable for the entirety of the `feed` function, cutting off access to `Profile` on the earlier line, `profile=Profile.objects.filter(user=user)`. The error occurs on line 40, but the *cause* of the error is on line 45. I edited the answer to add back the context so you can see where the bad line is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: @Gagan: If it completely answered your question, please up-vote and/or accept the answer (that's the usual way to acknowledge the question has been solved). IIRC, you even earn a little rep yourself when you accept an answer (that is not your own answer).